# Is Opera Version 12.15 using WebKit or Presto for its rendering engine?

Tags: browsers

I cannot tell from the [Opera Desktop team blog](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2013/04/04/12-15-final-released) or from the [Presto Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presto_%28layout_engine%29) if Opera 12.15 is utilizing the WebKit or Presto rendering engine. The phrasing from Wikipedia can be interpreted either way:

> It [Presto] remained in use until Opera 12.15, when the browser's developer
>   Opera Software ASA began phasing Presto out of its products in favor
>   of the WebKit layout engine and V8 JavaScript engine combined with a
>   modified Chromium browser.

Is Opera Version 12.15 using WebKit or Presto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12.15 is still using Presto, but it's being phased out after 12.15 in favour of <strike>WebKit</strike> Blink, a WebKit fork.

Comment: Actually it seems that Opera will switch to Blink (a webkit fork).

Answer (score 1):

Opera officially confirmed that they will follow Google with Blink.

"*Google on Wednesday made a huge announcement to fork WebKit and build a new rendering engine called Blink. Opera, which only recently decided to replace its own Presto rendering engine for WebKit, has confirmed with TNW that it will be following suit.*"

**Source**: http://thenextweb.com/insider/2013/04/04/opera-confirms-it-will-follow-google-and-ditch-webkit-for-blink-as-part-of-its-commitment-to-chromium/

According to user rafaelluik and [his](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1658432&t=1367530885&page=1#comment14157662) comment Opera 12.50 was renamed to 12.10. But there seems no official statement when they start to implement it.